# Symplectomorphism and Hodge decomposition

Tags: complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry, de-rham-cohomology

Let $X$ be some holomorphic symplectic manifold. This means we have choosen some $\omega\in H^{2,0}(X).$ If $f:X\rightarrow X$ is a symplectomorphism, then we have by definition
$$f^*\omega=\omega.$$
A symplectomorphism $f^*$ has an eigenvalue $1$ on $H^{2,0}(X)$. However, as was pointed out by Michael Albanese in the comments, this is not a sufficient condition, even if we assume that $X$ has a symplectic form. My question is if there exists a cohomological criterion for an endomorphism to be symplectic for some symplectic form.

Comment: If $h^{2,0}(X) \neq 0$, then $1$ is an eigenvalue of $f^*$ for $f = \operatorname{id}_X$.

Comment: Sure, then we would only need to show the existence of a symplectic form on $X$, no? That doesn't invalidate my question, no? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You're missing the fact that $h^{2,0}(X) \neq 0$ does not imply $X$ admits a holomorphic symplectic form.

Comment: Let me change my question accordingly.

Comment: This is false. Let $c$ be a constant map $K3 \to K3$, then for the map $f := \operatorname{id}_{K3}\times c : K3\times K3 \to K3\times K3$, the induced map $f^*$ on $H^{2,0}$ has $1$ as an eigenvalue, but the eigenspace consists of degenerate forms.

Comment: okey, lets disregard the eigenvalue buissness. My question is if there is some cohomological criterion for a morphism to be symplectic, do you happen to know if there is such a thing?

Comment: I am not aware of such a thing. I should also point out that I'm assuming you're talking about holomorphic symplectic manifolds, not manifolds which are complex and symplectic. I assumed the former because you wrote $\omega \in H^{2,0}(X)$.

Comment: I'm edditing the question to reflect your input, thanks!